# How to generate a matrix automatically with given n in matlab

Tags: matlab

For the linear regression, I want to generate the matrix for polynomials of n degree.

if n is 1

```
X=[x(:), ones(length(x),1)]
```

if n is 2

```
X=[x(:).^2 x(:) ones(length(x),1)]
```

...

if n is 5

```
X=[x(:).^5 x(:).^4 x(:).^3 x(:).^2 x(:) ones(length(x),1)]
```

I do not know how to code with matlab if I set n=6 and it will automatically generate the wanted X matrix. Hope you can help me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be easily done with [`bsxfun`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html):

```
X = bsxfun(@power, x(:), n:-1:0);
```

Or, in Matlab versions from R1016b onwards, you can use [implicit expansion](https://nickhigham.wordpress.com/2016/09/20/implicit-expansion-matlab-r2016b/):

```
X = x(:).^(n:-1:0);
```

Comment: @ycagelulu: If this solved your question, please accept the answer. https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/376604

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [polyval](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/polyval.html) function. I believe that will do what you’re looking for.

To get increasing the polynomial to increase in degree, you can increase the length of your `p` argument using a loop.

Comment: Thanks. But polyval actually needs polyfit function.

Answer (score 0):

If you write `edit polyfit` you can see how MATLAB have implemented the `polyfit` command, which is similar to what you are trying to do. In there you will find the code

```
% Construct the Vandermonde matrix V = [x.^n ... x.^2 x ones(size(x))]
V(:,n+1) = ones(length(x),1,class(x));
for j = n:-1:1
    V(:,j) = x.*V(:,j+1);
end
```

Which constructs the matrix you are interested in. The benefit of this method over the `bsxfun` is that you only calculate `x(:).^n` and then saves the intermediary results. Instead of treating all powers as seperate problems, e.g. `x(:)^(n-1)` as a seperate problem to `x(:).^n`.